# document.write() overwrites entire page

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

So, I was trying to make HTML appear at the click of a button, but instead of inserting the HTML right where the script tag was, the entire page was overwritten with the code that was supposed to be generated. After experimenting, I found that something simple like

```
document.write("<p>" + "Hello!" + "</p>")
```

would simply insert it as it should. On the other hand, the code I was trying to do replaced the entire page.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is some example code.

```
function writeIFrame() {
    document.write('<iframe width="500" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UJFdywQqovI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><p>Check out my YouTube channel <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkqJM5HVjuvPA9H1VuFU5pQ">here</a> and subscribe!');
}
```

Comment: `document.write()` is not a great way to manipulate page content. You can do this far more effectively by manipulating the DOM with the built-in methods or using a library like jQuery.

Comment: Simple: [don't use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) for DOM manipulation.

Comment: @HoboSapiens thank you for your information. I have been recently studying jQuery. What commands do you think is preferable for adding to the DOM and the most efficient?

Comment: @duskwuff What did you do to make the HTML tag reference appear correctly?

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist Placed it in a block indented with four spaces. Click the "edited … ago" link notice for details.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where your function is getting called.

If `document.write` is called after html loading complete. It would overwrite the whole page. (Because appending it after closing html tags causes wrong syntax, thus make no sense doing so.)

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years since you asked this so, I suppose you will know the answer but I've seen that nobody answered correctly yet:
document.write() will **always** overwrite all the document.

The best way to do what you were asking is to use the *.innerHTML* method with "+=" for example:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+= "Hi!";
```

And then you will have:

```
<p id="test"> Hi! </p>
```

Remark that `+=` will always keep what is already written. If we want to replace what is inside the `<p>` tag we must use only `=`.

I know that you will for sure know this nowadays, but I hope to somebody can find this question and maybe get a good answer with this. :)

Comment: There are already correct answers. It does not always overwrite the entire document, only if it's called after `document.close()` has been called. The browser calls `document.close()` after it finishes parsing the HTML.